# Javascript / Jquery file combination

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to include this snippet of code:

```html
;(function($) {

   'use strict'
   
   var ajaxContactForm = function() {
      // http://www.bitrepository.com/a-simple-ajax-contact-form-with-php-validation.html
      $('.contact-form').each(function() {
         var $this = $(this); 
         $this.submit(function() {
            var str = $this.serialize();
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url:  $this.attr('action'),
               data: str,
               success: function(msg) {
                  // Message Sent? Show the 'Thank You' message and hide the form
                  var result;
                  if(msg == 'OK') {
                     result = '<div class="notification_ok">Thank you! Your message has been sent!</div>';
                  } else {
                     result = msg;
                  }
                  result = '<div class="result">' + result + '</div>';
                  $this.find('.note').html(result);
               }
            });
            return false;
         }); // submit

      }); // each contactform
   }; // contact

   // Dom Ready
   $(function() {
      ajaxContactForm();
     
      
      // Initialize responsive menu
      ResponsiveMenu.initial($(window).width());
      $(window).resize(function() {
         ResponsiveMenu.menuWidthDetect($(this).width());
      });

      // Detect elements into viewport
      $('[data-waypoint-active="yes"]').waypoint(function() {
         $(this).trigger('on-appear');
      }, { offset: '90%' });

      $(window).on('load', function() {
         setTimeout(function() {
            $.waypoints('refresh');
         }, 100);
      });
   });

})(jQuery);
```

Into this file:
http://rocketgram.co/js/custom.js

However whenever I try and merge the two correctly (Or what I thought) I can only get one or the other working at once. Not both. Can anyone share any light on why these are conflicting?

Here's a few reference links on both of them working, singularly:
rocketgram.co/mainjs.html
rocketgram.co/customjs.html

And here's the file in the snipped above:
rocketgram.co/js/main.js

Comment: 1. Do you get any errors from the console? 2. How are you concatening them? In what order?

Comment: I'm very new to coding, I have checked the console and fixed the issue. The javascript was simply getting caught on a bad function. I apologize!